# How would I add URL subsections/subpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I add things like this:

/page/sub-section

ex: https://url.com/account/notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of a static site, each slash represents a single directory on your web server.

```
/page/sub-section
```

Would mean you have the

- `/` the root directory
- `/page` a folder called *page*
- `/sub-section` another folder called *sub-section*

In the last folder, you would then have your index file, which will be loaded once visiting the URL. For example `index.html`.

---

In terms of web development this is named routing and all the big web frameworks come with own modules for routing. Here you don't have to create directories as described above, instead these frameworks will handle the request and route it internally to find the right content and display it for that route.